# form-data in postman sending Empty object to node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I know this has been asked multiple times, but I have been looking around and still can't find an answer to my problem.

index.js file

```
const express = require("express");
require("dotenv").config({
  path: ".env",
});
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const runDatabase = require("./config/database");
const path = require('path')

const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use("/uploads", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "uploads")));

// routers
const userRouter = require("./router/usersRouter");
const categoryRouter = require("./router/categoryRouter");
const productRouter = require("./router/productRouter");

app.use("/api", userRouter);
app.use("/api", categoryRouter);
app.use("/api", productRouter);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  runDatabase();
  console.log(`The Backend Server is up and running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

controller file

```
exports.createCategory = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { title, sort } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body); // print empty object

    await categoryModel.create({
      title,
      sort,
    });
    return res.status(200).send("created");
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send(err.message);
  }
};
```

Here is my code, when sending the request in JSON raw postman a response is what I need but when using a form-data it will return an empty body

this is happened when I send data with form-data
returned an empty body
[image]

this is happened when I send data with raw (Json)
returned what i need
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use the option `"x-www-form-urlencoded"` I guess it will work. So here is the thing:

- When you are using postman's `"form-data"` it will be considered as `multipart/form-data` for which you need a library to parse form-data such as multer.
- For `x-www-from-urlencoded` raw data, you can parse the data using the express
  built-in middlewares or use a body-parser.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same error. The important part is in router file, where you construct post request:
example
router.post('/', upload.single('file'), ProductsController.create);

important part here is you should have upload.single('file') - file upload with this request and then form-data won't be empty. If you don't send file through middleware like this you body will be empty.
if you router is router.post('/', (without file), ProductsController.create); you will get empty body.